# Will creating a new app pool disrupt anything in IIS 6?

Tags: iis-6

I have a website in IIS 6, let's call it "WebSite1." I have a virtual application underneath it, let's call it "VirtualApp1." Both of these are set up to use the same application pool, "AppPool1." I want to create a new application pool, "NewAppPool," and switch VirtualApp1 to using it, while leaving the rest of WebSite1 running under AppPool1.

Will doing this cause disruption to anything in WebSite1? I know it will most likely trash VirtualApp1's appdomain, but I want to know if it's going to cause any appdomain/pool recycles that would disrupt WebSite1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done this many times on a production server, and never experienced any problems or hickups.

So I'd say: no, go ahead! :)

Comment: Marking as answered because yep, no discernible problem :)