# Will changing an application's app pool cause an outage or disruption in IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-7, application-pool

similar to the question asked here:

[will-creating-a-new-app-pool-disrupt-anything-in-iis-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094120/will-creating-a-new-app-pool-disrupt-anything-in-iis-6)

I have a site running in an app pool called 'Kiosks', while there are several applications as children of the site in IIS Manager running in various app pools.  I need to move one of these applications from an app pool called 'ASP.NET v4.0' to a new app pool I will be creating with a different name (but same configuration).

When I move the application to the new app pool, will this cause an outage for anyone currently in the app?  An outage scenario is not mentioned in this MS article:

[Change an Application Pool for a Site (IIS 7)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732992(v=ws.10).aspx)

and based on the behavior described in this thread, it seems like there should be no impact to the user:

[what-happens-on-an-application-pool-reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074016/what-happens-on-an-application-pool-reset)

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I would not describe that as an outage, although there would be a slight performance impact as the new pool has to load into memory anything it requires.  If everything goes well (no errors) this should be fairly equivalent to an application pool recycle.

The conditions under which you'd have impact would be if you have very-long-running transactions (e.g. a large file upload) that could be interrupted by switching pools, or if you're doing session state management in memory.  You are cleaning out your app domain after all.